# numbers converted to objects

Tags: javascript

i'm having trouble with some javascripting, where some values that are apparantly numbers, suddenly turn into objects, and i can't figure out how or why.

codesnippets:

```
addFigure("-1,1,-0.5_1,1,-0.5_0.5,-1,-0.5_-0.5,-1,-0.5");

function addFigure(t) {
        var fig = new figure();
        var v = t.split("_");

        var points = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            var coords = v[i].split(",");
            var x = parseFloat(coords[0]);
            var y = parseFloat(coords[1]);
            var z = parseFloat(coords[2]);
            alert(typeof x + " " +typeof y)
            var point = new Point3D(x, y, z);
            alert(typeof point.x + " " + typeof point.y)
           //both alerts print out "number number"
           fig.addPoint(point);
        }


        figures.push(fig);
    }

        function figure() {
        this.points = new Array();
        this.addPoint = function (x, y, z) {
            var v = new Point3D(x, y, z);
            alert(typeof x + " " + typeof y)
//this alert prints out "Object undefined"
            this.points.push(v)
        }

        this.getPoints = function () { return this.points }

    }
```

Comment: i'd recommend that you use a debugger like the Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug and step through line by line to inspect what's going on there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling your `addPoint` function with one parameter (a `Point3D`) here:

```
fig.addPoint(point);
```

But `addPoint` seems to expect the point as three separate parameters:

```
this.addPoint = function (x, y, z) {
```

So you would end up with `x` being the `Point3D` you passed in, and `y` and `z` being `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `addPoint()` method seems to expect the `x`, `y` and `z` properties to be passed separately, but you're passing just one parameter, the `point` object.

Either change the method to be:

```
this.addPoint(point) {
    /* x, y and z are now retrievable from point.x, point.y etc */
}
```

Or change the invocation to the method to be

```
fig.addPoint(point.x, point.y, point.z);
```